# How does Cassandra type cast a datatype internally when we are trying to write a Spark DataFrame into Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

To provide more insights on the question, when we are trying to write a String to a integer Column in Cassandra, how does Cassandra internally typecast or Conceive this String input as an integer ?

Cassandra Schema :

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace_name.table_name1 (
    col1 text,
    col2 int,
    col3 text,
    col4 text PRIMARY KEY (col1)
```

DataFrame Schema :

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is done via registration of type converters for different CQL types. For example, following code is defined for `int` type in the [PrimitiveColumnType.scala](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/PrimitiveColumnType.scala#L37):

```
case object IntType extends PrimitiveColumnType[Int] {
  def scalaTypeTag = implicitly[TypeTag[Int]]
  def cqlTypeName = "int"
  def converterToCassandra =
    new TypeConverter.OptionToNullConverter(TypeConverter.forType[java.lang.Integer])
}
```

This code uses generic `convert` [implementation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TypeConverter.scala#L40), that offloads actual conversion for type-specific implementation of to partial function `convertPF`. For [IntConverter](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/types/TypeConverter.scala#L155) that is able to convert to integer either from `Number` or from `String`:

```
def convertPF = {
  case x: Number => x.intValue
  case x: String => x.toInt
}
```

You can look for other implementations, for example, CQL `date` could be obtained from different types - string, long, UUID, ...

Comment: Thanks for the update! Now, I have got some essential understanding on this.